# AWS lambda UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I tried to test my lambda function on aws console, but I can't understand why this error is occuring.

```
[ERROR] UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 9: invalid continuation byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 208, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 164, in addpackage
    for n, line in enumerate(f):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
[ERROR] UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 9: invalid continuation byte Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 208, in addsitedir     addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)   File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site.py", line 164, in addpackage     for n, line in enumerate(f):   File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode     (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
```

Please give me some help to figure out this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There not much information because there no codes.
And it seems you used UTF-8 chars for path which only allows ascii or latin chars.
So would check your code is there any function only allows non-UTF-8 chars?